# Material-UI Button Component doesn't work properly after deploy on Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, material-ui, github-pages

```
<Button href={node.slug}>
  <span>Read more</span>
</Button>
```

So basically this is a button in a Card component, i don't think more code would present more meaning, please ask for more if needed. The node.slug variable is something like "product-name". In local environment works fine, but not after deployment on Github pages.

This is a button on a product-category page(i.e. /tools or /maintenance), clicking the button the first time, takes me to:

**xxx.github.io/project-name/product-name/**

Issue is that after i go back and then click the button again, /product-category/ gets added to the URL:

**xxx.github.io/project-name/product-category/product-name/**

This is not the link i want to be at, as there is no page here. The first URL is where i want to be, as that's the URL type where products are at. /product-category/ will not go away unless i click the Home Page button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I infer correctly `node.slug` is something like `"product-name"`.

That means that it is not an absolute path, and therefore you can interpret it as `./product-name`.

Try with:

```
<Button href={`/project-name/${node.slug}`}> ... </Button>
```

---

Another approach would be to change your base href of your pages. Add a `<base>` element in you `<head>`:

```
<head>
  ...
  <base href="http://xxx.github.io/project-name/">
</head>
```

Then all your non-absolute `href`s will start from that base.

Don’t forget to add a `/` at the end of the `base`’s `href`!